# How to make an HTTP request inside the DOM of Puppeteer via evaluate?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, puppeteer

How can I make a loaded page of Puppeteer make a request and return the result?

I tried this which does not work, and I have no idea why:

```
var result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var xhrto = setTimeout( function(){
            xhr.abort();
            resolve('ErrTimeout');
        }, 8000);
        xhr.onload = function(){
            clearTimeout(xhrto);
            if( xhr.status == 200 ){
                resolve(xhr.responseText);
            }else{
                resolve('ErrStatus:'+xhr.status);
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function(){
            resolve('Err');
        };
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.robotstxt.org/robots.txt', true);
        xhr.send();
    });
});
```

I always get 'Err' which means onerror is called.

Is there anything in Puppeteer/Chrome that prevents something outside of the page from making a request?

NOTE: for many reasons I must make the request from within the page.

**EDIT:** It definitely has to do with cross-domain and SSL issues because when I use HTTPS with `--disable-web-security` it works. But with HTTP it doesn't, even with all these:

```
--disable-web-security --allow-running-insecure-content --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://example.com --user-data-dir=/root/chromeusertest
```

Comment: See if this have what you want to do: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue

Not sure if i understood what you want to do, but it looks like the link above can help

Comment: You will probably get cross-domain errors unless you launch with --disable-web-security

Comment: Try changing the url to https://